# react native - collapse table

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I plan to make a collapse table. You can find it in this [link](https://medium.com/appnroll-publication/5-practical-solutions-to-make-responsive-data-tables-ff031c48b122)

I tried:

- Using a Custom Component for column name and FlatList for the first column
- Using Section list for the rest column

=============================================================
| _____Custom Component_____ | __________Section list header__________ |
|============================================================|
| _________Flat List___________| __________ Section list body____________|
|============================================================|

I am able to make the list scroll together. However, if the list has 450+ rows, the performance will be reduced dramatically.

Please let me know if you have any solution.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. The idea is.

1. Use Animated.ScrollView to control the horizontal scroll
2. Use FlatList to control the vertical scroll
3. When we do horizontal scroll, keep the first element of the FlatList and move the rest of them.

Below is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Animated, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View,} from 'react-native';
import * as UIConfig from "../../../../configs/UIConfig";
import * as ColorConfig from "../../../../configs/ColorConfig";

export interface CollapseTableColumnType {
    name: string,
    accessName: string,
    width: number,
    visible: boolean,
}

interface CollapseTableType {
    normalColumns: Array<CollapseTableColumnType>,
    collapseColumns: Array<CollapseTableColumnType>,
    data: Array<any>
}

interface State {
    scrollX: Animated.Value,
}

class CollapseTable extends Component<CollapseTableType, State> {

    // Data

    private _scrollView: any = null;
    private _flatList: FlatList<any> | null = null;

    static defaultProps: CollapseTableType = {
        normalColumns: [],
        collapseColumns: [],
        data: [],
    };

    state: State = {
        scrollX: new Animated.Value(0),
    };

    private _HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE = this.props.collapseColumns.concat(this.props.normalColumns)
        .reduce((totalWidth, currentWidth) => currentWidth.width + totalWidth, 0);

    private _headerTranslate = this.state.scrollX.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, this._HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
        outputRange: [0, this._HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
        extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });

    scrollToTop = () => {
        if (this._flatList) {
            this._flatList.scrollToOffset({ animated: false, offset: 0 });
        }
    };

    scrollToLeft = () => {
        if (this._scrollView) {
            this._scrollView.getNode().scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: false});
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Animated.ScrollView
                ref={(ref: any) => this._scrollView = ref}
                style={styles.fill}
                horizontal={true}
                removeClippedSubviews={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                scrollEventThrottle={1}
                onScroll={Animated.event(
                    [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {x: this.state.scrollX}}}],
                    {useNativeDriver: true},
                )}
            >
                <FlatList
                    ref={(ref: any) => this._flatList = ref}
                    removeClippedSubviews={true}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    data={this.props.data}
                    renderItem={this.renderRow}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'item_' + index}
                    stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
                    ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
                />
            </Animated.ScrollView>
        );
    }

    renderHeader = () => {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.cellContainer, {backgroundColor: ColorConfig.PRIMARY_90}]}>
                <View style={styles.normalCellContainer}>
                    {
                        this.props.normalColumns.map((config, indexConfig) => {
                            return this.renderCell(
                                indexConfig,
                                this.props.normalColumns[indexConfig].width,
                                this.props.normalColumns[indexConfig].name,
                                this.props.normalColumns[indexConfig].visible,
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </View>
                <Animated.View style={[
                    styles.collapseCellContainer,
                    {
                        position: 'absolute',
                        transform: [{translateX: this._headerTranslate}],
                        backgroundColor: ColorConfig.PRIMARY_90,
                    },
                ]}>
                    {
                        this.props.collapseColumns.map((config, indexConfig) => {
                            return this.renderCell(
                                indexConfig,
                                this.props.collapseColumns[indexConfig].width,
                                this.props.collapseColumns[indexConfig].name,
                                this.props.collapseColumns[indexConfig].visible,
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
        );
    };

    renderRow = ({item, index}: { item: any, index: number }) => {
        return (
            <View key={index} style={styles.cellContainer}>
                <View style={styles.normalCellContainer}>
                    {
                        this.props.normalColumns.map((config, indexConfig) => {
                            return this.renderCell(
                                indexConfig,
                                this.props.normalColumns[indexConfig].width,
                                item[this.props.normalColumns[indexConfig].accessName],
                                this.props.normalColumns[indexConfig].visible,
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </View>
                <Animated.View style={[
                    styles.collapseCellContainer,
                    {
                        position: 'absolute',
                        transform: [{translateX: this._headerTranslate}],
                        backgroundColor: ColorConfig.PRIMARY_97
                    },
                ]}>
                    {
                        this.props.collapseColumns.map((config, indexConfig) => {
                            return this.renderCell(
                                indexConfig,
                                this.props.collapseColumns[indexConfig].width,
                                item[this.props.collapseColumns[indexConfig].accessName],
                                this.props.collapseColumns[indexConfig].visible,
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
        );
    };

    renderCell = (index: number, width: number, text: string, visible: boolean) => {
        return (
            <View key={index} style={[styles.cell, {width: width, opacity: visible ? 1 : 0}]}>
                <Text style={styles.cellText}>{text}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    fill: {
        flex: 1,
    },

    // Header

    cellContainer: {
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    normalCellContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    collapseCellContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    cell: {
        paddingTop: 8 * UIConfig.RATIO,
        paddingBottom: 8 * UIConfig.RATIO,
        paddingLeft: 8 * UIConfig.RATIO,
        paddingRight: 8 * UIConfig.RATIO,

        borderRightColor: ColorConfig.PRIMARY_ALPHA_10,
        borderRightWidth: UIConfig.RATIO,
        borderBottomColor: ColorConfig.PRIMARY_ALPHA_10,
        borderBottomWidth: UIConfig.RATIO,

        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    cellText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: ColorConfig.PRIMARY,
        fontSize: 14 * UIConfig.RATIO,
    }
});

export default CollapseTable;
```

Hope this answer can help you like it did to me!